# Plugin specific config not loaded

Tags: vimrc, plugin-deoplete

I have in `.vim/after/plugin/` a file called `deoplete.vim`
Inside is this code

```
let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1 " Enable autocompletion at startup

" Autocomplete Deoplete + Vimtex
call deoplete#custom#var('omni', 'input_patterns', {
      \ 'tex': g:vimtex#re#deoplete
      \})
```

The code `let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1` is not loaded, although `:scriptnames` shows that the file is loaded. Also, `:verbose set completeopt?` shows `completeopt=menu,preview`.

If I source `deoplete.vim` in `.vimrc` the `let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1` is working.

If I remove `let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1` and put it in `.vimrc` the rest of the code is working without sourcing the file.

What am I missing?
I'm trying to clean my `.vimrc` file and put all the plugin config in `.vim/after/plugin/` and all the filetype config to `.vim/after/ftplugin/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime directories located in `~/.vim/after/*` are sourced after all user and plugin scripts in relevant directories (excluding `after/*`), then scripts in all plugin `after` directories and then user `after` directories.

Thus if you put your `let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1` into your `after`, it would only be sourced after your deoplete plugin is loaded and it means plugin didn't use it to actually find out you wanted to enable it at start up.

You can put it into `~/.vim/plugin/deoplete.vim` -- everything in `~/.vim/plugin/*.vim` would be auto sourced before any script in your installed plugins.

Might be useful:

- https://youtu.be/JFr28K65-5E
- `:h after-directory`
- `:h runtimepath`